# Javascript não funciona quando tento fazer mais de 2 tarefas

Tags: javascript, jquery, django-templates

Sou inciante em desenvolvimento web.
O script abaixo só funciona para o que faço no primeiro for, 
não sei o que estou fazendo errado. 
Quando deveria fazer o a parte do segundo for ele nem sequer entra nele.
Também não chama o alert logo após o primeiro loop for.
É como se logo após o primeiro for ele parasse.

`

```
            var setUnid = document.getElementById('unidadeVenda').value;
            var setUnid2 = document.getElementById('unidadeVendaAux');
            var unidDesc = '{% getIdUnidade %}';
            var array = unidDesc.split(',');
            var descUnid;

            for (i = 0; i < array.length; i++) {
                descUnid = array[i].split(':');
                if (descUnid[1].trim() == setUnid) {
                    setUnid2.value = descUnid[0].trim();
                }
            }

            alert('TESTE'); 

            var setCom = document.getElementById('agente').value;
            var setCom2 = document.getElementById('agenteVendaAux');
            var comDesc = '{% getIdAgente %}';
            var arrayCom = comDesc.split(',');
            var descCom;


            for (i = 0; i < arrayCom.length; i++) {
                    descCom = arrayCom[i].split(':');

                    if (descCom[1].trim() == setCom) {
                        setCom2.value = descCom[0].trim();
                        alert(descCom[0].trim());
                    }
            }
```

Comment: Podes juntar o HTML? como sabes que não entra no segundo `for`? algum erro na consola?

Comment: Bom dia Sergio, descobri que o problema esta quando uso o trim(). Por exemplo no primeiro for " descUnid[1].trim() " não entendi o motivo, mas se  utilizar desta forma " var desc = new String(descUnid[1]); "  e depois " desc.trim() " o meu problema não ocorre mais.

Comment: O que dá `console.log(typeof descUnid[1]);`?

Comment: console.log(typeof descUnid[1]);   dá string, porém vi que umas das informações deu "undefined"

Answer (score 1):

Descobri que o problema esta quando uso o trim(). Por exemplo no primeiro for " descUnid[1].trim() " não entendi o motivo, mas se utilizar desta forma " var desc = new String(descUnid[1]); " e depois " desc.trim() " o meu problema não ocorre mais.